# Code doesn't recognize serial numbers correctly

Tags: c++, openai-api

I asked gpt (don't know if questions about it are legal here) to write me a c++ program in which it assigns serial number input from user to product type. i made it assign serial numbers ranging from JGU 0001 to JGU 5000 to type Pdg, and serial numbers from JGU 5001 to JGU 9999 to type Skc. Unfortunately when I run the program in a compiler it displays serial codes from range JGU 5001-9999 still as Pdg. I also added all numbers with prefix JGA and JGB as Jg, but that works fine. Whenever i mention it gpt writes me another version, but it still doesn't work every time.  Here's the code it spat out:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <string>

using namespace std;

string getProductType(string serialNumber) {
    string prefix = serialNumber.substr(0, 3); // Extract prefix (e.g., "JGU", "JGA", "JGB")
    int number = stoi(serialNumber.substr(4)); // Extract number part and convert to integer

    if (prefix == "JGU") {
        if (number >= 1 && number <= 5000) {
            return "Pdg";
        } else if (number >= 5001 && number <= 9999) {
            return "Skc";
        }
    } else if ((prefix == "JGA" || prefix == "JGB") && number >= 1 && number <= 9999) {
        return "Jg";
    }
    return "Unknown"; // In case the serial number doesn't match any range
}

int main() {
    string serialNumber;
    cout << "Enter the serial number (e.g., JGU 1234): ";
    cin >> serialNumber;
    string productType = getProductType(serialNumber);
    cout << "Product Type: " << productType << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I've taken a look at the code and can't notice anything logically wrong with it. I tried a bunch of online compilers to make sure it wasn't fault of that one.

Comment: Don't you think you would learn more if you wrote your own code? In all seriousness you are only cheating yourself.

Comment: You should only ask questions about code you've written yourself. We are not going to review AI generated content. ChatGPT is just not good enough to write C++ code

Comment: I see with scare that GPT has learnt to start its C++ program(s) with `using namespace std;`... (I try to imagine what bad habits it might've learnt as well.)

Comment: @Scheff'sCat   It's a sign of how much sample C++ code (including that in both questions and answers on SO) do exactly that.   After all, ChatGPT might generate code, but it does that without understanding the purpose or reasoning (or lack of reasoning) for the code - it simply predicts what might be typed in based on, statistically, the code samples it has.

Answer (score 2):

The error is here

```
cin >> serialNumber;
```

it should be

```
getline(cin, serialNumber);
```

The problem with your code is that `cin >> ...` stops reading when it finds a space character. So the number part of your serial number is not read.

Using `getline` reads a whole line of text, which is clearly what you want.

Comment: And don't forget to invoke `cin.clear()` before `getline()` if you intend to put the user input into a loop otherwise you'll find another strange behavior. ;-)